# Python ctypes generator

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

Any advice on a generator for Python ctypes?  I see the following out there:

This is rather old (2005):
http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/old/codegen.html

This seems to have nothing to download:
http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/

Here's a possibility:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygccxml/files/ctypes%20code%20generator/

I am guessing I will be doing this by hand, but, was hoping for a head start.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ctypesgen, you can [use subversion](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/source/checkout) to check out the trunk. Another possibility might be [PyCParser](https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser).